# How to convert a character column to numeric in R

Tags: r, csv, integer, character, converters

**I write a R code in R 3.1.1**

I want to sum values of Ventas_filtradas$Total which belongs to class carácter. I have tried to use as.integer(x), as.numeric(x), colClasses in read.csv, but the coercion doesn´t work and happens one of two situations:

1) the coercion of "-0.055" results in NA.
2) the coercion of "-0.055" results in 1. This happens if I use type.convert(x,dec=",") and then I convert it to integer

This is the code:

```
        specdata<-setwd ("C:/Users/GMORENO/Documents/LUDESA DE COLOMBIA/Pronosticos R")
        ## Readlines, read all the lines of the file

        Todas_las_filas = readLines("ZSD_VENTAS_COMPLETO.xls")
        ## delete lines I do not need
        filtrar_filas = Todas_las_filas[-c(1:8,10)]
        ## 

        Ventas_filtradas = read.csv(textConnection(filtrar_filas), sep="\t", header = TRUE, dec=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

        classes <- sapply(Ventas_filtradas, class)
        classes<-as.data.frame(classes)
        classes[56,1]<-"numeric"
        classes<-as.vector(classes)

        Ventas_filtradas = read.table(textConnection(filtrar_filas), sep="\t", header = TRUE, dec=",", colClasses=classes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


Warning message:
In read.table(textConnection(filtrar_filas), sep = "\t", header = TRUE,  :
  not all columns named in 'colClasses' exist
    ##names of the columns 


c("\tNo. Factura\tFecha\tClase\tOrg. Ventas\tDescripción Org. Vtas.\tCanal\tDescripción Canal\tSector\tDescripción Sector\tOf.Ventas\tDescripción Of. Vtas\tGrupo\tDescripción Grupo\tVendedor\tNombre Vendedor\tCod. Cliente\tNombre Cliente\tGr. Clientes\tDescripción Gr. Clientes\tZona de Ventas\tDescripción Zna. Vtas\tCiudad\tDescripción Ciudad\tRegión\tDescripción Region\tRamo\tDescripción Ramo\tRamo 1\tDescripción Ramo 1\tGrupo precios\tDescripción Gr. Precios\tABC\tNo. Material\tDescripción del material\tCódigo exxon\tGrupo Articulos\tDescripción Gr. Art.\tTipo de pedido\tDescripción Tp. Ped.\tJerarquía\tJN1\tJerarquía Nivel 1\tJN2\tJerarquía Nivel 2\tJN3\tJerarquía Nivel 3\tJN4\tJerarquía Nivel 4\tJN5\tJerarquía Nivel 5\tCantidad Facturada\tUnidad Medida\t   Peso Neto\tCantidad\t      Total\t     Valor Neto\t      P. V. G.\t  P. T. G.\t% Variación.\tDoc. contable\tCentroBE\tUsuario\tLinea_bi\tAgencia\tHORA", 
"\t88004178\t02.07.2014\tZNCR\tLC01\tLudesa de Colombia\t15\tVTA.DCTA.VENDEDOR\t10\tLUBRICANTES\t8050\tBOGOTA\t010\tLUDESA BOGOTA\t00000348\tDANIEL MANTILLA\t30025339\tTRACTOCARGA LTDA\tC1\tB2B\tCWC100\tCentro Occidente\t1001\tBOGOTA, D.C.\t11\tBOGOTÁ\tD080\tSec.Transporte\tD08030\tS.Tran.Carg-Camiones\t00\tSin Grupo Precio\t\t           120714\tM-DELVAC XTREME GREASE - 1/180KG\t\t01\tLubricantes\t100\tNota crédito por precio alto\t010010020020030\t010\tLUBRICANTES\t010\tMOBIL\t020\tPREM\t020\tCVL\t030\tGRASAS\t-0,001\tTR\t-0,184\t 55,006\t-0,055\t-1.879.860,00\t34.179.272,73\t41.906,01\t  81.461,74\t2300003460\tL08110\tFATEHORTUA\tLUB\tBG01\t08:18:51", 
"\t88004179\t02.07.2014\tZFDR\tLC01\tLudesa de Colombia\t15\tVTA.DCTA.VENDEDOR\t10\tLUBRICANTES\t8050\tBOGOTA\t010\tLUDESA BOGOTA\t00000348\tDANIEL MANTILLA\t30025139\tMOTOR OIL SAS\tC2\tB2C\tCWN100\tNoroccidente\t1001\tBOGOTA, D.C.\t11\tBOGOTÁ\tD105\tCentro Lubricación\tD10510\tCentro lubr. Canal\t00\tSin Grupo Precio\t\t           121926\tM-SUPER 1000 20W-50 - GRANEL\t\t01\tLubricantes\t014\tPedido recibido via CORREO ELECTRONICO\t010010020010100\t010\tLUBRICANTES\t010\tMOBIL\t020\tPREM\t010\tPVL\t100\tMOTOR MULTIGRADO\t-200,000\tGL\t-2.612,000\t  1,000\t-200,000\t-8.234.934,00\t    41.174,67\t41.906,01\t-1,75\t2100031804\tL08110\tFALVIS\tLUB\tBG01\t10:02:51"
)
```

Comment: There is no R 3.11.  `a <- "-0.055" ; as.numeric(a)` #[1] -0.055 ; Since you have not produced any evidence that lets us determine where your errors are coming from this question is at risk of being closed as unclear. You should produce the lines of that file that are causing the problems. Also you cannot generally read in .xls files with readLines. It will create a big mess.

Comment: I'm confused, how is `readLines()` able to read a binary XLS file? (And I second @BondedDust's note. Additionally, please provide a piece of the data itself, using something like `dput(head(filtrar_filas))`, since I'm inferring your problem is in the second half of the script.)

Comment: Hello: I am new in R. You are right . I use R 3.1.1

Comment: Hello: I have added all the info needed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello: I have could solve it. the problem was the comma (,) . The solution was to extract all the string without the comma and then to convert them to integer.

```
totales<-c("0,055","-200,000","135,00")

totales2<- totales
## determine the amount of character of each item of the vector
num_caracteres<-nchar(totales)
## delete the last 4 characters
num_caracteres<-num_caracteres-4
## extract al the carácter without the (,)
totales2<- substring(totales, 1, num_caracteres)
totales3<- as.integer(totales2)
totales<-totales3
```